# Ripple conflict blackberry.app plugin

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I'm using BlackBerry WebWorks 2.2.0.15 on Ubuntu and the project shows before adding the app plugin.

I cannot preview home screen when adding the plugin `blackberry.app`, but it works on my device when published!

I did some research I found this [old](https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/com-blackberry-app-Error-when-preview/m-p/2700213/highlight/true#M41947) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple fix to continue the test using ripple by adding [JS errors](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp):

```
function getReadOnlyFields() {
try {
var success = function (data, response) {
readOnlyValues = data;
}, 
fail = function (data, response) {
throw data;
};
if (!readOnlyValues) { 
exec(success, fail, ID, "getReadOnlyFields", null);
}
}
catch(err) {
 console.log(err);
}
}
```